# Pass command line args to scripts run by hardhat run command

Tags: hardhat

How can I pass positional arguments to script run by `npx hardhat run` command?

Help displays only this:

```bash
Hardhat version 2.6.8

Usage: hardhat [GLOBAL OPTIONS] run [--no-compile] script

OPTIONS:

  --no-compile  Don't compile before running this task 

POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS:

  script        A js file to be run within hardhat's environment 

run: Runs a user-defined script after compiling the project

For global options help run: hardhat help
[4:38 PM]
If I try something like
npx hardhat --network mumbai run scripts/collect.js 2
Error HH308: Unrecognized positional argument 2

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH308 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

If I try

```bash
npx hardhat --network mumbai run scripts/collect.js 2
Error HH308: Unrecognized positional argument 2

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH308 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it is asking about the **2** in the run command what is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out this [link](https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html#creating-a-task)

Check out a custom example

```
task("erc20_balances", "Prints the list of erc20 balances").addParam("address", "Add token address").setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  try {
    const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");
    const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(taskArgs.address, abi, provider);
    for (const account of accounts) {
      balance = await contract.balanceOf(account.address);
      console.log(account.address, " : ", balance.toString());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

running scripts are of 2 kinds:

1. write a standalone scripts
2. write hardhat tasks with their references in hardhat config file

here the question is about the option-1, where we run script via:

```
npx hardhat run --network testnet <scriptname> --acct value --symbol value
```

@rlib
How are you accessing the arguments inside the script?
is it like this way?

```
const [acct, symbol] = args;
```

Comment: `npx hardhat --network polygon run scripts/initLadder.js --symbol  1

Error HH305: Unrecognized param --symbol`